# Assert function on basis of more than one response codes

Tags: javascript, node.js, assert, bearer-token

We have an API which requires token from another API response. Below I have cascaded the response of that API to the main API.

How do I add assert function for more than one response codes. For the main API the response code should return 200. But if token passed is wrong it returns 401. If main API is down it returns different response code.

So, I require a switch case type construct to check this in below code snippet, or a multiple assert block.

```
var assert = require('assert');
var request = require('request');
var options2,token,info;
var options = {

  'method': 'POST',

  'url': '**',

  'headers': {

    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

  },

  form: {

    'client_id': **,

    'client_secret': **,

    'grant_type': 'client_credentials'

  }

};

request(options, function (error, response) {

  if (error) throw new Error(error);

     info = JSON.parse(response.body);
     console.log(info.access_token);
     token=info.access_token;
  



var request = require('request');

var options2 = {

  'method': 'GET',

  'url': '**',

  'headers': {

    'Content-Type': 'application/json',

    "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
  }

};

request(options2, function (error, response) {

  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  
switch(response.statusCode)
    {
          
case '200' :assert.ok(response.statusCode != 200, 'Expected 200 response'); 
           break;
}
});
});
```

Comment: Why not do `assert.ok(response.statusCode === 200, 'Expected 200 response')`

Comment: @TomMcLean yes that can be done, but also I need separate expressions checks for different response codes. How do I do that?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do, you can use switch statements to handle different response codes.

Comment: Yes for each response code I need different message output. How do I use switch with assert?

Comment: I have added the switch statement but it doesnt seem to work. Check my OP.